# ¿Se pueden crear nuevas Activitys , dentro de Android con código nativo, para luego llamarlas en Dart/Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Se que se puede alojar vistas nativas de Android e iOS en la aplicación Flutter, con vistas de plataforma:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views?tab=ios-platform-views-swift-tab.

Pero mi intencion no es esa, es más cercana a si se puede hacer una llamada a una Activity que nosotros creamos dentro de Android nativo para luego llamarla desde nuestra app en Flutter y que muestre una segunda pantalla, por así decirlo.

Ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo de lo que intento hacer]

Creo que la integracion de Flutter con código nativo tanto para IOS como para Android no permiten este tipo de implementación, pero me gustaría saber si es posible o no, dado que no he encontrado ni documentación al respecto, ni ejemplos.

[image: finalidad]

Un saludo.

Comment: Si se puede, usa android studio, aunque no pude compartir la libreria creo por eso lo deje flutter, intenta capas le falle algo. Pero si puedes para ti usarla.

Comment: Piensa si de verdad necesitas hacer esto, Flutter puede agregarse a tu proyecto android si la mayoría esta hecho en Android si no haz la vista en Flutter (Que es mas sencillo) y si en tu caso requieres de una librería que esta disponible solo para java o kotlin puedes acceder por medio de canales. Como en https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels